# Take screenshot of screen or active window not using 3rd party software

Tags: javascript, windows, powershell, vbscript, screenshot

I was interested in being able to take a screenshot of the screen, or of the active window (as you would do with Alt+PrtSc), using only standard Windows "tools"/scripts. VB Script? PowerShell? No 3rd party software or something like that. You shouldn't have to install anything or need any admin permission that you normally wouldn't have.

The reason for this is for people who have issues on their computer (and who aren't close to computer gurus) would be able to send in a ticket to the helpdesk just using a button on a website for example. For some people to find the right buttons to take a screenshot and attaching it in an email is surprisingly cumbersome.

I found a very nice solution to this but it only works in browsers and not in other application windows:
[Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try this script http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/eeff544a-f690-4f6b-a586-11eea6fc5eb8
It worked well for me.

Comment: I tried both those scripts and unfortunately I have to change the [Execution Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/sv-SE/library/hh847748.aspx) in PowerShell to make it run. By default I have Undefined in all scopes, but that defaults to "Restricted" and I guess I'm not the only one with this kind of configuration.

Comment: Create a bat file that runs Powershell with `-exec bypass` switch to get around the default execution policy. Or, pass the program as Base64 encoded with `-EncodedCommand <base64stuff>`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I found a very good guide just for this purpose. Altough in this case two files are necessary. Any idea how I would manage this with only one file to execute? http://blog.danskingdom.com/allow-others-to-run-your-powershell-scripts-from-a-batch-file-they-will-love-you-for-it/